# Is the expression "Liver's ability to detoxify alcohol was tested..."

Tags: grammar, expressions

Is the expression "Liver's ability to detoxify alcohol was tested..." grammatically correct? Can it also be used for genes, for example: "C-MYC's role in cancer is well known". This is, can gene molecules, organs and other body parts be used as such in sentences like the ones in the examples?

Comment: Why do you think there might be something wrong with those sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, livers, genes etc. possess properties. In english, that possession is often indicated via an apostrophe ess.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you're asking about the ***-'s*** possessive suffix. There's no problem with that. There **is** a problem, however, with the use of *Liver* in

> *Liver's ability to detoxify alcohol was tested..*

Without an article, *liver* is a meat, a mass noun like *beef*, never treated as a count noun:

> *I had a liver last night for supper.*

(Well, almost never; Hannibal Lector is an outlier. But the fact that the thought occurs is why the count construction's avoided.)

Presumably, this sentence is about an experiment. Generally, the construction used there would be a [Definite Generic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html) *The liver*.

> *The liver's ability to detoxify alcohol was tested..*

... and, one more quibble. Epistemologically, one can't actually "test" a generic; ***the*** generic ***liver*** doesn't exist and is not available for testing -- it's a platonic ideal.